# How to combine multiple QuerySets in Django?

Tags: python, django, search, django-queryset, django-q

I'm trying to build the search for a Django site I am building, and in that search, I am searching across three different models. And to get pagination on the search result list, I would like to use a generic object_list view to display the results. But to do that, I have to merge three QuerySets into one.

How can I do that? I've tried this:

```
result_list = []
page_list = Page.objects.filter(
    Q(title__icontains=cleaned_search_term) |
    Q(body__icontains=cleaned_search_term))
article_list = Article.objects.filter(
    Q(title__icontains=cleaned_search_term) |
    Q(body__icontains=cleaned_search_term) |
    Q(tags__icontains=cleaned_search_term))
post_list = Post.objects.filter(
    Q(title__icontains=cleaned_search_term) |
    Q(body__icontains=cleaned_search_term) |
    Q(tags__icontains=cleaned_search_term))

for x in page_list:
    result_list.append(x)
for x in article_list:
    result_list.append(x)
for x in post_list:
    result_list.append(x)

return object_list(
    request,
    queryset=result_list,
    template_object_name='result',
    paginate_by=10,
    extra_context={
        'search_term': search_term},
    template_name="search/result_list.html")
```

But this doesn't work. I get an error when I try to use that list in the generic view. The list is missing the clone attribute.

How can I merge the three lists, `page_list`, `article_list` and `post_list`?

Comment: Looks like t_rybik has created a comprehensive solution at http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1933/

Comment: For searching it's better to use dedicated solutions like [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) - it's very flexible.

Comment: Django users 1.11 and abv, see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42186970/6003362

Comment: *note*: the question is limited to the very rare case when after merging 3 different models together you don't need extracting models again on the listing to distinguish data on types. For most cases - if distinction is expected - it will wrong interface. For the same models: see answers about `union`.

Answer (score 1238, accepted):

Concatenating the querysets into a list is the simplest approach. If the database will be hit for all querysets anyway (e.g. because the result needs to be sorted), this won't add further cost.

```
from itertools import chain
result_list = list(chain(page_list, article_list, post_list))
```

Using `itertools.chain` is faster than looping each list and appending elements one by one, since `itertools` is implemented in C. It also consumes less memory than converting each queryset into a list before concatenating.

Now it's possible to sort the resulting list e.g. by date (as requested in hasen j's comment to another answer). The `sorted()` function conveniently accepts a generator and returns a list:

```
from operator import attrgetter
result_list = sorted(
    chain(page_list, article_list, post_list),
    key=attrgetter('date_created')
)
```

You can reverse the sort order:

```
result_list = sorted(
    chain(page_list, article_list, post_list),
    key=attrgetter('date_created'),
    reverse=True,
)
```

`attrgetter` is equivalet to the following `lambda` (this was the way it had to be done before Python 2.4):

```
result_list = sorted(
    chain(page_list, article_list, post_list),
    key=lambda instance: instance.date_created,
)
```

Comment: If merging querysets from the same table to perform an OR query, and have duplicated rows you can eliminate them with the groupby function: 
`from itertools import groupby`
`unique_results = [rows.next() for (key, rows) in groupby(result_list, key=lambda obj: obj.id)]`

Comment: Ok, so nm about the groupby function in this context. With the the Q function you should be able to perform any OR query you need: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: is it possible to use `list.extend` instead of `chain`?

Comment: What happens if there are duplicates? Will it remove them or will I need to add some extra code to do so?

Comment: I have two lists like this
x = [{ "id":"value", "name":"value", "date":"value"},..,..,...] and the other list also like this. I am trying to arrange it according to date. Will this work?

Comment: I had to sort by a field whose type was the same across 3 different data models, but were named differently. I worked around this by writing a model method within each model to normalize access... Article.title, Event.name and News.topic all got a ``get_object_name`` method. Worked like a charm! (and also works for ImageFields)

Comment: @apelliciari Chain uses significantly less memory than list.extend, because it doesn't need to load both lists fully into memory.

Comment: @JoshRusso Your link above is dead

Comment: @AWrightIV Here's the new version of that link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: trying this approacg but have `'list' object has no attribute 'complex_filter'`

Comment: Since you're fetching a lot of model instances, but only require a few fields for each, I do suggest adding [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#only) to the queryset for optimization.

Comment: @akaihola so I'm still uncertain here about if the sort() call is done here as above, is it going to load the entire queryset into memory to perform the sort?

Comment: @Purrell do you mean the `sorted()` call? That's going to evaluate any iterator you hand to it for sure. So yes, the queryset is going to be in memory.

Comment: @akaihola Yeah figured. So... I wonder how to combine querysets for pagination, with order by date, in a way that actually scales ... Seems like a Paginator feature request. Or perhaps your QuerySetChain answer https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1933/

Comment: Well @Purrell if you think about it, it's not possible to do pagination on the Django side optimally. Even if each of query results is sorted and you merge them intelligently, you can't know the optimal offsets and limits to query for a given page. You can make a good guess, but you'll always end up either querying lots of extra rows, or having to do extra queries, or both. Dropping down to raw SQL and chaining+sorting on the database side will give you better performance.

Comment: Thanks, this was massively helpful. As a note, this returns a list containing model class objects that can be operated on. Initially I thought it returned strings!

Comment: This answer made me start to be active in SO, editing and answering questions, in order to get enough reputation so i could upvote it.

Comment: @JoshRusso I got an AttributeError: 'itertools._grouper' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: How can `sorted` with `key=attrgetter('date_created')` in reverse order?

Comment: @parmer_110, the `sorted()` function supports a `reversed=` keyword argument. See [documentation for sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

Answer (score 585):

Try this:

```
matches = pages | articles | posts
```

It retains all the functions of the querysets which is nice if you want to `order_by` or similar.

**Please note:** this doesn't work on querysets from two different models.

Comment: Doesn't work on sliced querysets, though. Or am I missing something?

Comment: | seems to be more like list + than set |, i.e., it can create duplicates.

Comment: I used to join the querysets using "|" but not always works fine. It's better to use "Q": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q

Comment: It does not seem to create duplicates, using Django 1.6.

Comment: Here `|` is the set union operator, not bitwise OR.

Comment: @e100 no, it's not the set union operator.  django overloads the bitwise OR operator: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L308

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that the order will be preserved, correct?

Comment: @IgnacioPérez Django provides an OR on both QuerySet and Q so depending on the scenario either may be appropriate.

Comment: @sthzg It is because you need to be conscious of whether your slicing operation is returning a [QuerySet or a list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) - if it is a QuerySet then the OR operation is implemented but this is not the case with a list.

Comment: `Cannot combine queries once a slice has been taken.` So, not useful if queryset is sliced.

Comment: Note that this solution does *not* preserve ordering, so a set `{x,y,x}` and a set `{a,b,c}` may end up `{a,b,c,x,y,z}` regardless of whether you use `s1 | s2` or `s2 | s1` and that makes `|` somewhat useless in many cases.

Comment: Does not work for objects containing geodjango geometries.

Comment: i used over my first project over django and it's beauty of django. i really love it.

Answer (score 168):

Related, for mixing querysets from the same model, or for similar fields from a few models, *starting* with **Django 1.11** a [`QuerySet.union()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.union) is also available:

> **`union()`**
>
> ```
> union(*other_qs, all=False)
> ```
>
> **New in Django 1.11**. Uses SQL’s UNION operator to combine the results of two or more QuerySets. For example:
>
> ```
> >>> qs1.union(qs2, qs3)
> ```
>
> The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use the all=True
> argument.
>
> union(), intersection(), and difference() return model instances of
> the type of the first QuerySet even if the arguments are QuerySets of
> other models. Passing different models works as long as the SELECT
> list is the same in all QuerySets (at least the types, the names don’t
> matter as long as the types in the same order).
>
> In addition, only LIMIT, OFFSET, and ORDER BY (i.e. slicing and
> order_by()) are allowed on the resulting QuerySet. Further, **databases
> place restrictions on what operations are allowed in the combined
> queries.** For example, most databases don’t allow LIMIT or OFFSET in
> the combined queries.

Comment: This is a better solution for my problem set that needs to have unique values.

Comment: Where do you import union from though? Does it have to come from one of the X number of querysets?

Comment: Yes, it is a method of queryset.

Comment: I think it removes search filters

Comment: Keep in mind you **won't be able** to `filter()` this queryset anymore after using `union()`. `filter()` will just **fail silently**. At least in Django 2.2

Comment: Be careful when using `union` in the admin site: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62711963

Answer (score 83):

You can use the `QuerySetChain` class below. When using it with Django's paginator, it should only hit the database with `COUNT(*)` queries for all querysets and `SELECT()` queries only for those querysets whose records are displayed on the current page.

Note that you need to specify `template_name=` if using a `QuerySetChain` with generic views, even if the chained querysets all use the same model.

```
from itertools import islice, chain

class QuerySetChain(object):
    """
    Chains multiple subquerysets (possibly of different models) and behaves as
    one queryset.  Supports minimal methods needed for use with
    django.core.paginator.
    """

    def __init__(self, *subquerysets):
        self.querysets = subquerysets

    def count(self):
        """
        Performs a .count() for all subquerysets and returns the number of
        records as an integer.
        """
        return sum(qs.count() for qs in self.querysets)

    def _clone(self):
        "Returns a clone of this queryset chain"
        return self.__class__(*self.querysets)

    def _all(self):
        "Iterates records in all subquerysets"
        return chain(*self.querysets)

    def __getitem__(self, ndx):
        """
        Retrieves an item or slice from the chained set of results from all
        subquerysets.
        """
        if type(ndx) is slice:
            return list(islice(self._all(), ndx.start, ndx.stop, ndx.step or 1))
        else:
            return islice(self._all(), ndx, ndx+1).next()
```

In your example, the usage would be:

```
pages = Page.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=cleaned_search_term) |
                            Q(body__icontains=cleaned_search_term))
articles = Article.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=cleaned_search_term) |
                                  Q(body__icontains=cleaned_search_term) |
                                  Q(tags__icontains=cleaned_search_term))
posts = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=cleaned_search_term) |
                            Q(body__icontains=cleaned_search_term) | 
                            Q(tags__icontains=cleaned_search_term))
matches = QuerySetChain(pages, articles, posts)
```

Then use `matches` with the paginator like you used `result_list` in your example.

The `itertools` module was introduced in Python 2.3, so it should be available in all Python versions Django runs on.

Comment: Nice approach, but one problem I see here is that the query sets are appended "head-to-tail". What if each queryset is ordered by date and one needs the combined-set to also be ordered by date?

Comment: This certaintly looks promising, great, I'll have to try that, but i dont have time today. I'll get back to you if it solves my problem. Great work.

Comment: Ok, I had to try today, but it didnt work, first it complained that it didnt have to _clone attribute so i added that one, just copied the _all and that worked, but it seems that the paginator has some problem with this queryset. I get this paginator error: "len() of unsized object"

Comment: @Espen It seems that since revision 8121 of Django the paginator always first tries to call the count() method. If your Django is older than that, try renaming count() to __len__().

Comment: @hasen If sorting is needed, a simple list concatenation works best (if you don't want to do tricks with the database schema). See the "Concatenating the querysets into a list..." answer.

Comment: @akaihola Hmmm, still having problem with this, I've tried to add a __len__() and a len() function, but it still complains about "len() of unsized object". You can se the problem in action here: <url>http://drommestipendet.hyperinteraktiv.no/sok/?q=lorem&content-type=text</url>

Comment: @akaihola Sorry, the right url is:

http://drommestipendet.hyperinteraktiv.no/sok/?q=lorem&content-type=text

Comment: @Espen I added a proper _clone() method to the class. It should now work with the object_list generic view, if template_name= is specified.

Comment: @akaihola Hey, now its getting there, but not yet. Iam really sorry for the hazzle. It without the pagination. But with it i get an "integer required error" in the __get_item__ function. You can see the error here:

http://drommestipendet.hyperinteraktiv.no/sok/?q=lorem&content-type=text

Sorry...

Comment: @Espen We hit a difference between Python 2.4 and 2.5. In 2.5 the islice function accepts a step value of None and interprets it as 1. The fix is trivial. By the way, I sense that learning Python debugging techniques plus some Django specific tricks would benefit you a lot. Amazing stuff out there.

Comment: @akaihola Thanks! You've been most helpful! And yes, i should learn more, definitly, ive just started using Django and Python so there is a lot to learn, but im getting there slowly. Any tips on where to get good resources on debugging? Thanks again!

Comment: @Espen Python library: pdb, logging. External: IPython, ipdb, django-logging, django-debug-toolbar, django-command-extensions, werkzeug. Use print statements in code or use the logging module. Above all, learn to introspect in the shell. Google for blog posts about debugging Django. Glad to help!

Comment: @patrick see http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1103/ and http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1933/ – epecially the latter is a very comprehensive solution

Answer (score 43):

In case you want to chain a lot of querysets, try this:

```
from itertools import chain
result = list(chain(*docs))
```

where: docs is a list of querysets

Comment: How can sort these result? I have tried `results.reverse()` but not works.

Answer (score 32):

The big downside of your current approach is its inefficiency with large search result sets, as you have to pull down the entire result set from the database each time, even though you only intend to display one page of results.

In order to only pull down the objects you actually need from the database, you have to use pagination on a QuerySet, not a list.  If you do this, Django actually slices the QuerySet before the query is executed, so the SQL query will use OFFSET and LIMIT to only get the records you will actually display.  But you can't do this unless you can cram your search into a single query somehow.

Given that all three of your models have title and body fields, why not use [model inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)?  Just have all three models inherit from a common ancestor that has title and body, and perform the search as a single query on the ancestor model.

Answer (score 31):

This can be achieved by two ways either.

**1st way to do this**

Use union operator for QuerySet `|` to take union of two QuerySets. If both QuerySets belongs to the same model / a single model then it is possible to combine QuerySets by using the union operator.

*For an instance*

```
pagelist1 = Page.objects.filter(
    Q(title__icontains=cleaned_search_term) | 
    Q(body__icontains=cleaned_search_term))
pagelist2 = Page.objects.filter(
    Q(title__icontains=cleaned_search_term) | 
    Q(body__icontains=cleaned_search_term))
combined_list = pagelist1 | pagelist2 # this would take union of two querysets
```

**2nd way to do this**

One other way to achieve combine operations between two QuerySets is to use the **itertools** chain function.

```
from itertools import chain
combined_results = list(chain(pagelist1, pagelist2))
```

Comment: Instead of `itertools.chain` (which runs each query separately), `functools.reduce(operator.or_, [pagelist1, pagelist2])` can be used to programmatically apply your first approach. This results in a single query.

Answer (score 22):

You can use [Union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#union):

```
qs = qs1.union(qs2, qs3)
```

But if you want to apply `order_by` on the foreign models of the combined queryset... then you need to [Select](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) them beforehand this way... otherwise it won't work.

Example

```
qs = qs1.union(qs2.select_related("foreignModel"), qs3.select_related("foreignModel"))
qs.order_by("foreignModel__prop1")
```

where `prop1` is a property in the foreign model.

Answer (score 16):

```
DATE_FIELD_MAPPING = {
    Model1: 'date',
    Model2: 'pubdate',
}

def my_key_func(obj):
    return getattr(obj, DATE_FIELD_MAPPING[type(obj)])

And then sorted(chain(Model1.objects.all(), Model2.objects.all()), key=my_key_func)
```

Quoted from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/6wUNuJa4jVw. See **Alex Gaynor**

Answer (score 9):

**Requirements:**
`Django==2.0.2`, `django-querysetsequence==0.8`

In case you want to combine `querysets` and still come out with a `QuerySet`, you might want to check out [django-queryset-sequence](https://github.com/percipient/django-querysetsequence).

But one note about it. It only takes two `querysets` as it's argument. But with python `reduce` you can always apply it to multiple `queryset`s.

```
from functools import reduce
from queryset_sequence import QuerySetSequence

combined_queryset = reduce(QuerySetSequence, list_of_queryset)
```

And that's it. Below is a situation I ran into and how I employed `list comprehension`, `reduce` and `django-queryset-sequence`

```
from functools import reduce
from django.shortcuts import render    
from queryset_sequence import QuerySetSequence

class People(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mentor = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='my_mentees')

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# as a mentor, I want to see all the books owned by all my mentees in one view.
def mentee_books(request):
    template = "my_mentee_books.html"
    mentor = People.objects.get(user=request.user)
    my_mentees = mentor.my_mentees.all() # returns QuerySet of all my mentees
    mentee_books = reduce(QuerySetSequence, [each.book_set.all() for each in my_mentees])

    return render(request, template, {'mentee_books' : mentee_books})
```

Comment: Does `Book.objects.filter(owner__mentor=mentor)` not do the same thing? I'm not sure this is a valid use-case. I think a `Book` might need to have multiple `owner`s before you needed to start doing anything like this.

Comment: Yeah it does the same thing. I tried it. Anyway, perhaps this could be useful in some other situation. Thanks for pointing that out. You don't exactly start out knowing all the shortcuts as a beginner. Sometimes you gotta travel the load winding road to appreciate the crow's fly

Answer (score 6):

Here's an idea... just pull down one full page of results from each of the three and then throw out the 20 least useful ones... this eliminates the large querysets and that way you only sacrifice a little performance instead of a lot.

Answer (score 6):

The best option is to use the Django built-in methods:

```py
# Union method
result_list = page_list.union(article_list, post_list)
```

That will return the union of all the objects in those querysets.

If you want to get just the objects that are in the three querysets, you will love the built-in method of querysets, `intersection`.

```py
# intersection method
result_list = page_list.intersection(article_list, post_list)
```

Answer (score 5):

This will do the work without using any other libraries:

```
result_list = page_list | article_list | post_list
```

Comment: Worth noting that this may not retain the order of your results

Answer (score 3):

You can use ["|"(bitwise or)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators#The_Operators:) to combine the querysets of the same model as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Food
from django.http import HttpResponse
                                                
def test(request):
                                             # ↓ Bitwise or
    result = Food.objects.filter(name='Apple') | Food.objects.filter(name='Orange')
    print(result)
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Output on console:

```
<QuerySet [<Food: Apple>, <Food: Orange>]>
[22/Jan/2023 12:51:44] "GET /store/test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9
```

And, you can use `|=` to add the queryset of the same model as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Food
from django.http import HttpResponse
                                                
def test(request):
    result = Food.objects.filter(name='Apple')
         # ↓↓ Here
    result |= Food.objects.filter(name='Orange')
    print(result)
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Output on console:

```
<QuerySet [<Food: Apple>, <Food: Orange>]>
[22/Jan/2023 12:51:44] "GET /store/test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9
```

Be careful, if adding the queryset of a different model as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Food, Drink
from django.http import HttpResponse
                                                
def test(request):
          # "Food" model                      # "Drink" model
    result = Food.objects.filter(name='Apple') | Drink.objects.filter(name='Milk')
    print(result)
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

There is an error below:

```
AssertionError: Cannot combine queries on two different base models.
[22/Jan/2023 13:40:54] "GET /store/test/ HTTP/1.1" 500 96025
```

But, if adding the empty queryset of a different model as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Food, Drink
from django.http import HttpResponse
                                                
def test(request):
          # "Food" model                       # Empty queryset of "Drink" model 
    result = Food.objects.filter(name='Apple') | Drink.objects.none()
    print(result)
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

There is no error below:

```
<QuerySet [<Food: Apple>]>
[22/Jan/2023 13:51:09] "GET /store/test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9
```

Again be careful, if adding the object by [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Food
from django.http import HttpResponse
                                                
def test(request):
    result = Food.objects.filter(name='Apple')
                         # ↓↓ Object
    result |= Food.objects.get(name='Orange')
    print(result)
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

There is an error below:

```
AttributeError: 'Food' object has no attribute '_known_related_objects'
[22/Jan/2023 13:55:57] "GET /store/test/ HTTP/1.1" 500 95748
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the **intersection** of both querysets:

```
result = first_queryset.intersection(second_queryset)
```

Answer (score -3):

This recursive function concatenates array of querysets into one queryset.

```
def merge_query(ar):
    if len(ar) ==0:
        return [ar]
    while len(ar)>1:
        tmp=ar[0] | ar[1]
        ar[0]=tmp
        ar.pop(1)
        return ar
```

Comment: I am literally lost.

Comment: we combining query result it cannot be use at run-time and that really bad idea to do that. because sometime it's add duplication over result.

Comment: Too much complex , and the recursion results in a resources burn in the server.