# Django: union of different queryset on the same model

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I'm programming a search on a model and I have a problem.

My model is almost like:

```
class Serials(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.CharField("Code", max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=2000)
```

and I have in the database tuples like these:

```
1   BOSTON   The new Boston
2   NYT      New York journal
3   NEWTON   The old journal of Mass
4   ANEWVIEW The view of the young people
```

If I search for the string `new`, what I want to have is:

- first the `names` that start with the string
- then the `codes` that start with the string
- then the `names` that contain the string
- then the `codes` that contain the string

So the previous list should appear in the following way:

```
2   NYT      New York journal
3   NEWTON   The old journal of Mass
1   BOSTON   The new Boston
4   ANEWVIEW The view of the young people
```

The only way I found to have this kind of result is to make different searches (if I put "OR" in a single search, I loose the order I want).

My problem is that the code of the template that shows the result is really redundant and honestly very ugly, because I have to repeat the same code for all the 4 different querysets. And the worse thing is that I cannot use the pagination!

Now, since the structure of the different querysets is the same, I'm wandering if there is a way to join the 4 querysets and give the template only one queryset.

Comment: Starting from version 1.11, django query sets have a builtin union method. I have added it as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make those four queries and then chain them inside your program:

```
result = itertools.chain(qs1, qs2, qs3, qs4)
```

but this doesn't seem to nice because your have to make for queries.

You can also write your own sql using raw sql, for example:

```
Serials.objects.raw(sql_string)
```

Also look at this:

[How to combine 2 or more querysets in a Django view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view)

Comment: the other solution is perfect!

Answer (score 5):

You should also be able to do `qs1 | qs2 | qs3 | qs4`. This will give you duplicates, however.

What you might want to look into is `Q()` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q
value = "new"
Serials.objects.filter(Q(name__startswith=value) |
                       Q(code__startswith=value) |
                       Q(name__contains=value) |
                       Q(code__contains=value).distinct()
```

I'm not sure if it will handle the ordering if you do it this way, as this would rely on the db doing that.

Indeed, even using `qs1 | qs2` may cause the order to be determined by the db. That might be the drawback (and reason why you might need at least two queries).

Comment: by using Q() objects will the result be duplicated?

Comment: That line of code is rather long, but there is a `.distinct()` at the end.

Comment: Upvoting for the use of distinct. The answer using itertools on the other hand implements SQL 'UNION ALL'.

Comment: This is the best answer here - but it should noted that you can't do this with different django models.