# How to create Union in Django queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST Framework in project and I want to create union two different Models.

**My Models**

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True)
    geometry = models.GeometryField(blank=True, null=True)
    abwrapper= models.ForeignKey(ABWrapper)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tbl_a'

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True)
    link = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    geometry = models.GeometryField(blank=True, null=True)
    abwrapper= models.ForeignKey(ABWrapper)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tbl_b'
```

I am trying to create this query

```
SELECT id,name FROM tbl_a UNION (SELECT b.id,b.name From tbl_b b)
```

**My attempt for union**

```
a = A.objects.values_list('id')
b = B.objects.values_list('id')
queryset = a | b

Error:
AssertionError: Cannot combine queries on two different base models.
```

**Now i tried with parent Model in this way**

```
class ABWrapper(models.Model):
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'ab_wrapper'
```

Added this model as ForeignKey above both Models

```
a = ABWrapper.objects.filter(a__isnull=False).values('a__id')
b = ABWrapper.objects.filter(b__isnull=False).values('b__id')
queryset = a | b

Error:
TypeError: Merging 'GeoValuesQuerySet' classes must involve the same values in each case.
```

**Another attempt by making alias**

```
a = ABWrapper.objects.filter(a__isnull=False).extra(select={'tempID':'a__id'}).values_list('tempID')
b = ABWrapper.objects.filter(b__isnull=False).extra(select={'tempID':'b__id'}).values_list('tempID')
queryset = a | b

Error:
ValueError: When merging querysets using 'or', you cannot have extra(select=...) on both sides.
```

I have searched on it, mostly answered this issue as using list for both models. But I don't want to use list as I am using Django Rest Framework so I need QuerySet. So my question if I use list for union can I convert resulting list into QuerySet.

**Note:** I don't want to use SQL Query in Django

Is there any other way to do this task?

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300735/django-union-of-different-queryset-on-the-same-model

Comment: Above question does not return queryset

Comment: from django.db.models import Q
    queryset = ABWrapper.objects.filter(Q(a__isnull=False)|Q(b__isnull=False)`
does not work ?

Comment: Very late to the party, but I ran into this and ended up writing a little wrapper..  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-compoundqueryset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the union of two Django querysets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411049/how-can-i-find-the-union-of-two-django-querysets)

Comment: 1.11 added .union() to QuerySet, see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411049/how-can-i-find-the-union-of-two-django-querysets

Answer (score 1):

You can use Q objects in django for complex filtering.Look at [this_link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for implementation details.