# How to return model and models related to this model with many-to-many relationships

Tags: django, django-models, django-syndication

I have two models. Comment and his "Subcomments":

```
class Comment(models.Model):

    ....
    author = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
    subcomments = models.ManyToManyField('Subcomment', blank=True)
    ....


class Subcomment(models.Model):

    ....
    author = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    mcomment = models.ForeignKey(Comment)
    ....
```

I trying to make RSS subscribtion to post comments. I use following code:

```
class EntryCommentsFeed(Feed):

    ....
    def items(self, obj):
        return Comment.not_spam.filter(post=obj).order_by('-published')[:15]
    ....
```

But It returns only Comments without subcomments, and i don't have any idea how to return comment itself with his 'subcomments' and order by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. Model querysets are only ever composed of objects of that model type. You can loop through the returned `Comment`s and get the `Subcomment`s for each, though:

```
for comment in Comment.not_spam.filter(post=obj).order_by('-published')[:15]:
    subcomments = comment.subcomment_set.all()
```

Comment: Yeah, this works. I hoped have a better solution. Thanks for reply =]

Comment: Strange.. I defined the function - http://pastie.org/private/6oo8ttmawyfrkd21ouyhq , but django return error - http://pastie.org/private/z59dl06elgsafwnpx4wlfa . Strange thing is that, both models have get_absolute_url..

Comment: Not so strange. The feeds app is expecting a single iterative queryset. You passed it a list of querysets. That's not going to work. Use `itertools.chain` to combine the two querysets (http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). Realize, though, there's not going to be any hierarchy to your feed, i.e. `Subcomment`s are not going to be associated with `Comment`s. Everything will just be inline.

Comment: Fount that topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view Trying this, but have a new error `1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'`. Google near  six hours on  a solution, but i didn't find it. I think i should learn pure SQL and "delve" into the django ORM before i can do this. Thank you for help =)