# Creating a queryset which represents a union of querysets

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Let's say I have the following models:

```
class House(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    home = models.ForeignKey(House, null=True, related_name='tenants')

class Car(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Let's say I have a need (strange one, albeit) to get:

- list of people who live in a house or are named 'John'
- list of cars of the above people

I would like to have two functions:

- `get_tenants_or_johns(house)`
- `get_cars_of_tenants_or_johns(house)`

I could define them as:

```
from django.db.models.query_utils import Q

def get_cars_of_tenants_or_johns(house):
    is_john = Q(owner__in=Person.objects.filter(name='John'))
    is_tenant = Q(owner__in=house.tenants.all())
    return Car.filter(is_john | is_tenant)

def get_tenants_or_johns(house):
    johns = Person.objects.filter(name='John')
    tenants = house.tenants.all()
    return set(johns) | set(tenants)
```

The problem is that the logic is repeated in the above examples. If I could get `get_tenants_or_johns(house)` to return a `queryset` I could define `get_cars_of_tenants_or_johns(house)` as:

```
def get_cars_of_tenants_or_johns(house):
    return Car.objects.filter(owner__in=get_tenants_or_johns(house))
```

In order to do that, `get_tenants_or_johns(house)` would need to return a union of querysets, without turning them into other collections.

I cannot figure out how to implement `get_tenants_or_johns(house)` so that it would return a  queryset containing a SQL `UNION`. Is there a way to do that? If not, is there an alternate way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `|` operator on two querysets will return a new queryset representing a union.

The function will need to change to (got rid of `set()` wrappers):

```
def get_tenants_or_johns(house):
    johns = Person.objects.filter(name='John')
    tenants = house.tenants.all()
    return johns | tenants
```

and everything will work exactly like needed.

Answer (score 0):

You mention users who live in a house, but have no mention of your User model.

I think you really need to take a long look at the structure of your application - there are probably much easier ways to accomplish your goal.

But to answer your question let's set up three helper functions. Since, as I mentioned above, you haven't outlined what you want to do with the User class - I've assumed that the `house` that will be passed to these functions is an address:

helpers.py

```
def get_johns(house):
    is_john = Person.objects.filter(name='John')
    return is_john

def get_cars_of_tenants(house):
    cars = Car.objects.filter(owner__home__address=house)
    return cars

def get_tenants(house):
    tenants = Person.objects.filter(home__address=house)
    return tenants
```

Now you could create a view for each of your combination queries:

views.py:

```
import helpers.py
from itertools import chain

def get_cars_of_tenants_or_johns(request, house):
    results = list(chain(get_cars_of_tenants(house), get_johns(house)))
    return render_to_response('cars_or_johns.html', {"results": results,})

def get_tenants_or_johns(request, house):
    results = list(chain(get_tenants(house), get_johns(house)))
    return render_to_response('tenants_or_johns.html', {"results": results,})
```

And this can go on for all of the various combinations. What is returned is `results` which is a list of all of the matches that you can iterate over.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It was a late night question and I included many typos. I did not mean to refer to User objects, but rather Person objects. I have modified the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion `tenants + johns` does not work, although I very much wish it had. It throws a `TypeError` `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'`. While my original question sounds silly, it is an analogous problem to one I am facing professionally (which is more complicated but requires similar functionality). I wish it had not been voted down as it is a valid problem.

Comment: I've edited my post to use itertools `chain` to combine the QuerySets. Please try that. For more insight as to why/how this works, I would suggest checking out the itertools docs and this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view

Comment: I've found the answer I was looking for. It is the `|` operator on querysets. it does exactly what I needed. It is important for me to keep the querysets returned by the above functions as querysets and not turn them into lists, sets, or other containers. This way, I can  call `.delete()` and `.count()` on these querysets.