# django optimize merging querysets

Tags: django, django-queryset

For example, I have 2 querysets:

```
q1=MyModel.objects.filter(visible=True)
q2=MyModel.objects.filter(published=True)
```

And i need to make single queryset or list having all objects from q1 and q2.

I used to do it like this:

```
q=list(chain(q1,q2))
#q= q1 | q2 #this gives me not all objects from q2 or q1,so i don't use bitwise or
```

But it was said, that `list()` will produce extra queries to database. Is it true? And if it is, can somebody specify the most optimized way to do the merge?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view

Comment: read carefully what i'm asking for one more time before posting comments.

Comment: Allright then `q = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(visible=True) | Q(published=True))`. This will be the union of both querysets. `list()` doesn't produce extra queries but forces the queryset to be evaluated directly which will lead to extra overhead in memory.

Comment: thanks for the list() explanation, but you also could read p.s. part of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
q1=MyModel.objects.filter(visible=True)
q2=MyModel.objects.filter(published=True)
qs12 = QuerySetSequence(qs1, qs2)
```

Combine the above code with this snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1933/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this:

```
q1_pks = MyModel.objects.filter(visible=True).values_list('pk', flat=True)
q2_pks = MyModel.objects.filter(published=True).values_list('pk', flat=True)

final_query = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=list(q1_pks).extend(list(q2_pks)))
```

That should do the trick, although i'm not sure if those `list(qX_pks)` produce performances issues or not.