# How to combine two queryset lists in django with first list after the second list

Tags: python, django

I have below queryset in my code.

```
new_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=7)
most_viewd_list = mytable.objects.filter(show_on_website=True).order_by('-most_viewd')
new_list = most_viewd_list.filter(date_created__gte=new_date)
```

Now, i want to create a new list (results_list) which will have new_list rows at the beginning followed by most_viewed_list.

I have tried the options mentioned in [How to combine 2 or more querysets in a Django view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view), but none of them are working.

I tried below option...

```
 from itertools import chain
 result_list = list(chain(new_list, most_viewd_list))
```

But with this option if i use result_list.count(), it is throwing an error.

And with  results_list = new_list | most_viewd_list    option, i am not getting the desired result.

Can anyone tell me how i can create a list which will have new_list rows followed by most_viewed_list rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is creating a list (of the type you want). You take the length of a list with `len`: `len(result_list)`.

Answer (score 1):

Take an empty list like this

```
result_list=[]
result_list.append(most_viewd_list)
result_list.append(new_list)
```

Ex:

```
a = [66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5]
>>> print a.count(333), a.count(66.25), a.count('x')
2 1 0
>>> a.append(333)
>>> a
[66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5, 333]
```