# how to create an empty queryset and to add objects manually in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to create a queryset and to add manually some objects that i've got from different queries results in order to display it in a table.
I uses xx=set() but it doesn't do the job.

Comment: can you show the relevant code ?

Comment: How to create an empty queryset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#none

Comment: and how to add objects to it?

Comment: You say "some **objects**" are they evaluated members of previous querysets or do you simply mean "various querysets" that you'd like to chain together?

Comment: various querysets results to display in a table

Comment: This answer may help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/432666/671485)

Comment: I don't understand why this question has so many upvotes - it is not even clear what the person is asking about.

Comment: Were you able to get this done? Even I want to pass a custom list instead of a querylist.

Answer (score 36):

You can do it in one of the following ways:

```
from itertools import chain
#compute the list dynamically here:
my_obj_list = list(obj1, obj2, ...)
#and then 
none_qs = MyModel.objects.none()
qs = list(chain(none_qs, my_obj_list))
```

You could also do:

```
none_qs = MyModel.objects.none()
qs = none_qs | sub_qs_1 | sub_qs_2
```

However, This would *not* work for sliced querysets

Comment: how to add dynamically?

Comment: dynamically create a list, and then append it at once.

Comment: actually, you dont need the `none` qs. You could simply create a list and pass it in the context.

Comment: Does not work. type(qs) = list

Comment: @dz210 what are you trying to do? = is assignment, == is equality check.

Comment: @karthikr I am trying to manually create a queryset from a list of objects. My comment was a bit of a shorthand. The type of qs is still a list in the first code sample you gave - looking at it now it should be obvious.

Comment: Were you able to get this done? Even I want to pass a custom list instead of a querylist. I am unable to use the chain method working.

Comment: Were you able to get this done? Even I want to pass a custom list instead of a querylist. I am unable to use this list method working. Its is giving me a valueerror from the admin view. I am using this in a `filter` > `queryset(self, request, queryset)` The custom list is a created list and is not a queryset

Answer (score 14):

You can't do that. A queryset is a representation of a database query. You can't add items to it manually.

But if you need an arbitrary ordered collection of model instances, just use a list.

Comment: the problem with the list that i can't display it on a table created from a model

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Show some code.

Comment: for x in xx:
        
        query=Xx.objects.filter(id=x.id)
        lisst.append(query)
table = getXtable(lisst)

Comment: And am I supposed to guess what `getXtable` is, or why it doesn't work?

Comment: Were you able to get this done? Even I want to pass a custom list instead of a querylist. I am unable to use this list method working. Its is giving me a valueerror from the admin view. I am using this in a `filter` > `queryset(self, request, queryset)` The custom list is a created list and is not a queryset

Answer (score 14):

I'm really late to this one, but for a future reference you can create a queryset with all then filter for the objects that have a particular property.

#### Filtering on field object properties

```
Model.objects.filter(foo='bar')
Model.objects.exclude(foo='bar')
```

#### Filtering on non-field object properties

```
def return_queryset_with_desired_objects(self):
    qs = SomeModel.objects.all()
    wanted_ids = [obj.id for obj in qs if obj.foo]
    return self.filter(id__in=wanted_ids]

def return_queryset_without_undesired_objects(self):
    qs = SomeModel.objects.all()
    unwanted_ids = [obj.id for obj in qs if not obj.foo]
    return self.exclude(id__in=unwanted_ids]
```

Comment: `unwanted_ids = [obj.id for obj in qs if not obj.foo]` would mean a flock of trips to the database. Try `unwanted_ids=SomeModel.objects.filter(foo=False).values_list('id', flat=True)`

Comment: @mehmet I cleared up my answer. Hope it makes more sense now!

Comment: I still think the list comprehension you do would bring the objects to the python side, probably in just 1 trip, but bringing entire objects would be more of a load on the database than just bringing a `values_list`.

Comment: @mehmet You can't call a method on a values_list.