# Django model class inheritance with non managed classes

Tags: python, django, model, multiple-inheritance, django-rest-framework

I have a simple REST API that I would like to use Django and the DJANGO REST Framework for.  To start I need to connect to 2 different remote databases and get a recordset of unique countries from each.  I would then like to combine those record-sets into one model class.  I would like to keep each recordset in a separate classes for use in other areas of the API.

I have tried using Model class inheritance but I have not been able to get that to work with non managed tables.  This is the latest version of the Model.

```
class CountryA(models.Model):
    Country = models.CharField(db_column='field_country_country_value',primary_key = True, max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        managed = False

class CountryB(models.Model):
    Country = models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        managed = False

class CombinedCountries(ACountry,BCountry): 
    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

Django still seems to look for a local table for CombinedCountires.  I've also tried as a Proxy table without abstraction but it then looks for mcapi.content_field_country_country the field from CountryA as the table name.  I'm sure there must be a way to do this in the Model with remote tables but it's obviously not a common use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better solution for your problem will be to chain results from both models and use the final result as input list for API.

[How to combine 2 or more querysets in a Django view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view)

Comment: Yeah we did something similar in the view, the problem is we are using ViewSets from the REST Framework and it requires a QuerySet be passed to the serializer function.

Comment: Essentially what we did was import the chain results into the data model as it's own managed table.  NOt exactly what we wanted because it creates a duplicate data store, but close enough.