# concatenating 2 django query result into one

Tags: python, django

```
res= table.objects.values('lat','lng')
res1 = table1.objects.values('lat','lng')

res1=[{'lat': u'22.216021036729217', 'lng': u'84.83377508819103'}]
res=[{'lat': u'15.898394035175443', 'lng': u'73.82306920364499'}]
```

I want to add result of `res` and `res1` into `poi`:

```
poi = [{'lat': u'15.898394035175443', 'lng': u'73.82306920364499'},{'lat': u'22.216021036729217', 'lng': u'84.83377508819103'} ]
```

I have tried `poi=list(res)+list(res1)` but got the following error:

```
list referenced before assignment
```

Comment: see this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list operator to convert ValuesQuerySet into list

```
res= table.objects.values('lat','lng') res1 = table 1.objects.values('lat','lng')

poi = list(res) + list(res1)
```

Comment: that is exactly what i am doing but i get

    "list referenced before assignment" error

Comment: This is not giving me any error , I tried it. Can you please write down the exact code you are using.

Comment: Or try to do this. poi = list(django_query1) + list(django_query2)

Comment: the thing i was trying and you suggested was right, turned out i had a variable named "list" because of which was getting the error