# Django - How to combine queries in to one and display it in the template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

Suppose this is a model for an app Blog:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = BleachField()
```

And this is another model for an app Status:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    content = BleachField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

How do I come up with something like this:

```
from blog.models import Blog
from status.models import Status

blog = Blog.objecs.all()
status = Status.objects.all()
all = blog | status
```

And display all the updates for the user in the template.

```
updates = user.all_set.all()
```

**Edit:**

So that in the templates I can do, something like this:

```
{% for each in all %}
    ....
{% endfor %}
```

What I wan't is that, in the home page, I would like to display the updates of all the user's activity  in the latest order,

Eg:

```
'User updated with new status: blah blah'
'User published a new Blog'
'User published a new Blog'
```

like in many other social networking sites. And not to display them both separately. And similarly in the user's profile, display all the activities of that particular User.

Comment: You can't combine them at SQL level for sure, because the required schema projections are different (an outstanding difference, the number of queried columns is different).

Comment: Are you just looking to merge the two querysets? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view

Comment: If you want to have an activity feed you should look into an app that accomplishes that like [`django-activity-stream`](https://www.google.com/search?q=django+activity+feed) as you will need to incorporate nouns ("updated" or "published") and actors ("bob" or "jane")

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony OK. I think django-activity-stream is what I am looking for. Bur can I filter like, whether or not to display the activities only to the follower and so on, using django-activity-stream?

Answer (score 1):

You should use django proxy models for this, here's the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).

Here's an example:

```
class BlogAndStatus(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()
    is_blog = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class BlogManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(BlogManager, self).get_query_set().filter(is_status=True)


class Blog(BlogAndStatus):
    objects = BlogManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_blog = True
        return super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class StatusManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(StatusManager, self).get_query_set().filter(is_blog=True)


class Status(BlogAndStatus):
    objects = StatusManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_status = True
        return super(Status, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can get all objects with:

```
BlogAndStatus.objects.all()
```

or, using the manager, just Status with:

```
Status.objects.all()
```

You can use regular model forms in your forms.py, just make sure you set the field 'is_blog' or 'is_status' as True. An example for Blog:

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BlogForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['is_blog'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('title', 'content', 'is_blog')
        widget = {'is_blog': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

Comment: A form for Blog, Status or both?

Comment: For both in different forms.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a small example. Please mark the answer as accepted if you think I've answered your first question.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why you have such a weird model; but the best you can do is this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def foo(request):
   photo = Photo.objects.filter(creator=request.user)
   status = Status.objects.filter(creator=request.user)
   context = {'photo': photo, 'status': status}
   return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Then in your template:

```
<h4>Photos:</h4>
  <ul>
  {% for p in photo %}
     <li>{{ p }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
<h4>Status:</h4>
  <ul>
  {% for s in status %}
     <li>{{ s }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

Comment: Yes, I could have done this. But I don't want to display them separately. I want to display them according to latest activity. Please check the edit.