# Concatenate queryset in django

Tags: django, pagination

I want to concatenate two queryset obtained from two different models and i can do it using itertools like this:

```
ci = ContributorImage.objects.all()
pf = Portfolio.objects.all()
cpf = itertools.chain(ci,pf)
```

But the real fix is paginating results.If i pass a iterator(cpf, or our concatenated queryset) to `Paginator` function, `p = Paginator(cpf, 10)`, it works as well but fails at retrieving first page `page1 = p.page(1)` with an error which says:

> TypeError: object of type 'itertools.chain' has no len()

What can i do in case like this ?

Comment: I know if i evaluate ci pf by wraping them in list(), this will solve my objective but i guess that will bloat memory and will be inefficient, correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The `itertools.chain()` [will return a generator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). The  [`Paginator` class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/paginator.py) needs an object implementing `__len__` (generators, of course *do not* support it since the size of the collection is not known).

Your problem could be resolved in a number of ways (including using `list` to evaluate the generator as you mention) however I recommending taking a look at the `QuerySetChain` mentioned in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/432666/119071

I think it fits exactly to your problem. Also take a look at the comments of that answer - they are really enlightening :)

Comment: Using list() to evaluate the generator is a neat solution, worked for me in a similar case, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but because I encountered this error, I would answer to this question.

you should return a list of objects:

```
ci = ContributorImage.objects.all()
pf = Portfolio.objects.all()
cpf = itertools.chain(ci,pf)

cpf_list = list(cpf)
```