# How to get all data from different models?

Tags: django, django-models

I have models:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = ...
    content = ...
    creationdate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    [etc]

class Model_A(models.Model):
    name = ...
    info = ...
    news = models.ManyToManyfield(News)
    [etc]

class Model_B(models.Model):
    field_b = ...
    info = ...
    news = models.ManyToManyfield(News)
    [etc]
```

And I want to get news from model_a and model_b, sort by creationdate. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have `model_a_inst` as one of objects of `Model_A` you can do

```
model_a_inst.news.all().order_by('creationdate')
```

Comment: It's ok to get one queryset. I think op is looking for a way to concatenate two querysets. Perhaps this will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/434755/1344854