# Is it possible to sort 2 querysets with attributes of same type?

Tags: python, django

somewhere in my view, I'm creating querysets this way :

```
scan_events = ScanEvent.objects.order_by('scan_date')

userewards_events = UseRewardEvent.objects.order_by('use_date')
```

Now I'd like to send to my template one list containing both objects sorted by scan_date /use_date (which of course are both Django DateTimeField).

If I simply "append" my 2 querysets to a new list, they won't be sorted by Date.
I guess there is a simple way to do that, but can't find it.

What I'm trying to display in my page is ONE table with The type of Event, and the date.
This means I have to be able to know the type of objects in my list, when displaying them in the template.

Thanks.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/434755/631348

Comment: I'm actually trying to solve this using Multi-table inheritance (creating an Event class with a date attribute). I'll detail the solution if it works as expected. Thx for the link thought.