# how to do this in python django

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField()
   year = models.IntegerField()

class ModelTwo(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField()
   year = models.IntegerField()
```

and respectively their Entry Models

```
class EntryCenter(models.Model)
   name = models.TextField()
   user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="user_entrycenters") 

class EntryOne(models.Model)
   entrycenter = models.ForeignKey(EntryCenter,related_name="center_one_entries")
   model_one = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne,related_name="model_one_entries")
   added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="user_one_entries") 

class EntryTwo(models.Model)
   entrycenter = models.ForeignKey(EntryCenter,related_name="center_two_entries")
   model_two = models.ForeignKey(ModelTwo,related_name="model_two_entries") 
   added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="user_two_entries")
```

and now i am in `EntryCenter XY`, i need to query both entries in this Center and sort them by `year` with `oldest year first` and render to template.

```
center = EntryCenter.objects.get(id=1)#<-- EntryCenter XY
one = center.center_one_entries.order_by('model_one__year')
two = center.center_two_entries.order_by('model_two__year')
entries = sorted(chain(one, two), key=lambda obj: obj.year)
```

`one` is for example `[1, 3, 4]`
`two` is for example `[2, 5, 6]`

i need `[1,2,3,5,4,6]`, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Does `key=lambda obj: getattr(obj, 'model_one', getattr(obj, 'model_two')).year` work?

Comment: @alecxe, thanks dude, but i changed my question.. first one was my typo. but your solution might help me with the second question as well.. let me check

Comment: Well, speaking about the first question..take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view