# How to merge multiple query sets in DJANGO

Tags: python, django

I have to merge the querysets below in a single list:

```
result_list_1 = Col.objects.defer("tags").filter(producer__username__icontains=crit) 
result_list_2 = Col.objects.defer("tags").filter(name__icontains=crit)
result_list_3 = Col.objects.defer("tags").filter(description__icontains=crit)
result_list_4 = Col.objects.filter(tags__name__icontains=crit)
...
```

Each result_list contains items, which have a unique numeric id I can use to make sure there are no dups.

I can't use | while querying the DB or Q objects.

How do I merge the resulsets in one single list?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view

Comment: Thanks Alex, I saw that one. There is a reference in a comment about merging elements without duplicates, but it is not very clear.

Comment: Thanks Steinar, no Q objects.

Comment: But why? If you give us some context to your problem it might be easier to provide you with a solution.

Comment: The code sample above shows only 4 querysets, but I actually have a lot more, some of them with way more complex filtering criteria. They cannot be combined. I have to merge the resulting querysets.

Comment: What about bitwise operations on the *querysets*? (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/796381/835002)) E.g: `result_list_1 | result_list_2` etc.

Comment: What you call "bitwise operations" works perfect. There should be a different name to call that though. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5):

What about a slight modification of `itertools.chain` that makes sure you don't get dupes:

```
def unique_chain(*iterables):
    known_ids = set()
    for it in iterables:
        for element in it:
            if element.id not in known_ids:
                known_ids.add(element.id)
                yield element
```

With that you can create your combined list:

```
combined_list = list(unique_chain(result_list_1, result_list_2, ... ))
```

Comment: Thanks Steffens. That did the trick. I suspect there might be more efficient methods but this one works.

Comment: I hate to rely on this technique but for quick prototyping, it saved my day. Now I just need to find an efficient applicable solution. Yeah its time complexity that takes my time But thank you

Answer (score 3):

Then you can't have a `QuerySet` and it's django-related functionality, but you can use `itertools.chain` which is specifically for merging multiple iterables.

```
import itertools

merged = itertools.chain(qs1, qs2, qs3, qs4)

for element in merged:
    print(element)
```