# Django 1.6 Adding to object in ListView's object_list

Tags: django

In Django 1.6, I have a list view. I want to add a couple of properties to each object in object_list. The way I am doing it now, is just over writing the object_list with the last filtered query. How can I add `answered_count` and `unanswered_count` properties to each object in object_list? For instance:

```
    {% for user in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ user.answered_count }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.unanswered_count }}</td>
    </tr>


class CommunityProfileListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = CommunityProfile

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(CommunityProfileListView, self).get_queryset()
        qs = qs.filter(threadvault__unanswered=False).annotate(
                answered_count=Count('threadvault'))
        qs = qs.filter(threadvault__unanswered=True).annotate(
                unanswered_count=Count('threadvault'))
        return qs
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use [itertools.chain(*iterables)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

Then, you can create two different querysets and join them together in object_list.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view) post.