# Easiest way to concatenate two QuerySets same Model (no order needed)

Tags: python, django

I am beginner to Django. I am trying to concatenate two QuerySets from the same Model. I don't need them to be in any specific order.

```
 normal_events = Events.objects.filter(date__day=day,is_weekly=False)
 weekly_events = Events.objects.filter(date__day=day%7,is_weekly=True)
```

I've tired this solution:

```
 events=normal_events + weekly_events
```

but obviously it doesn't work.

I saw this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/434755/3279262 and it works fine, but it is meant for different QuerySets.

Is there some simple way for same QuerySets?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine 2 or more querysets in a Django view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of concatenating you can use Q objects and combine them with |

```
events = Events.objects.filter(Q(date__day=day,is_weekly=False) | Q(date__day=day%7,is_weekly=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to concatenate in any order, then you could try something like this:

```
events = normal_events | weekly_events
```

Which is very similar to what you wanted to try initially.