# Django Form 'list' object has no attribute 'iterator'

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm new to django and I'm trying to concatenate different querysets from different models based on this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/434755/4465450

I keep getting this error when I try to view it in my admin.

`'list' object has no attribute 'iterator'`

I'm calling it in my forms.py

```python
 from django import forms
 from itertools import chain
 from content.models import Article, Tutorial

 class DashboardChoiceForm(forms.Modelform):
     dashboard_select = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(DashboardChoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         article_list = Article.objects.all()
         tutorial_list = Tutorial.objects.all()
         self.fields['dashboard_select'].queryset = list(chain(article_list, tutorial_list))
```

And I'm including it on my admin page like so:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from .forms import *

class RowSingleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = RowSingle
    form = DashboardChoiceForm
```

What I'm trying to do is create a dropdown on the RowSingle admin so that a user can select one content item (either article or tutorial) to display in that row.

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso 
`/Users/mashedpotatoes/Sites/myproject/myproject-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in __iter__, line 1102`
I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but let me know if that's not it.

Comment: Do you have a local variable named `list` ?

Comment: @karthikr I don't. The only time I use `list` is on the `chain`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line won't work:

```
self.fields['dashboard_select'].queryset = list(chain(article_list, tutorial_list))
```

The problem does not come from the right part, but from the left. The `ModelChoiceField` expects `queryset` to be an actual queryset, not a list.

If you want to supply a list, you should use another field type, namely a `ChoiceField`. Then you will need to assign the choices. They must be a list of 2-tuples, where first item is the actual value and the second item is the displayed text.

It becomes a bit tricky as the actual value must be a string, or something that can be converted to a string. For instance, we could do something like "article_<pk>" for articles and "tutorial_<pk>" for tutorials.

```
choices = chain(
    ('article_%d' % obj.pk, str(obj)) for obj in article_list),
    ('tutorial_%d' % obj.pk, str(obj)) for obj in tutorial_list),
)
self.fields['dashboard_select'].choices = choices
```

You may replace the `str(obj)` with whatever is a sensible way to display the object to the user.

And then when your form is validated you will get the value, which you should parse back:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, ValidationError

# on your form class
def clean_dashboard_select(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['dashboard_select'] # will be, eg: "article_42"
    try:
        typename, value = data.split('_')
        pk = int(value)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValidationError('cannot understand %s' % data)
    try:
        if typename == 'article':
            return Article.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if typename == 'tutorial':
            return Tutorial.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise ValidationError('No %s with pk %d' % (typename, pk))
    raise ValidationError('Never heard of type %s' % typename)
```

Edit (from comment) — to add section groups, change the choices like this:

```
choices = (
    ('Articles', tuple(('article_%d' % obj.pk, str(obj)) for obj in article_list)),
    ('Tutorials', tuple(('tutorial_%d' % obj.pk, str(obj)) for obj in tutorial_list)),
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this to me! However, instead of displaying 'article_%d', it shows the unicode that I set up in the models. I'm okay with that, but is there an explanation for that? Also, is it possible to add headers to each section before the choices? Like a heading of 'Article' and then all of the article selections, then a heading of 'Tutorial,' etc.

Comment: Well, you see the `chain` call with the two iterations? On the left of the line, it builds a tuple of 2 items. First item will be 'article_%d', it is not shown to the user, it's the internal value that you will get back for parsing. Second item is what to display. In the example I put `str(obj)`, which will use the model's `__unicode__`/`__str__` but you can replace that with whatever you like.

Comment: In the end, whatever you set on `choices` must follow the format specified in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices). Have a look there, it is explained how to have section headings.

Comment: I'm running into some more trouble. I looked at the documentation and I'm trying to set up headers like this:
`choices = chain(('Articles', (('article_%d' % obj.pk, str(obj) for obj in article_list))),)`

But I keep getting this error:
`('article_%d' % obj.pk, str(obj) for obj in article_list) SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

When I add more parentheses to group:
`(('article_%d' % obj.pk, str(obj)) for obj in article_list)`

Nothing shows up in the choice form.

Comment: I appended something on section titles to the answer above ^^