# Django - combine one queryset into another queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model Book with a foreign key to model Publisher.

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
   ...

class Book(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    ...
```

Is it possible to get one publisher with its all books (or with some condition)? So the values of the queryset may like below:

```
publishers = Publisher.objects.filter(name__isstartwith='publisher')
publishers_dict = publishers.values()

[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "publisher_a",
    "books":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "book_name_1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "book_name_2"
        },
    ]
}]
```

This seems a combination of two querysets in [How to combine 2 or more querysets in a Django view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view), but they are not quite the same. 
And there is a way to combine them after get the list of the query:

```
publishers = Publisher.objects.filter(name__isstartwith='publisher')
publishers = list(publishers)
# then filter the publishers to get all books from is
for pub in publishers:
    books = Books.objects.filter(publish=pub["id"])
    books = list(books)
    setattr(pub, "books", books)
```

But is it possible to use a QuerySet without iterating the publishers?

Comment: Are you asking about serialization of related objects, or just about how to get them in one go? Because `prefetch_related` will do the latter.

Comment: that seems what I am looking for. Thanks a lot about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the reverse lookup in django

```
books = publisher.book_set.all()
```

But you still need to iterate over the publishers.