# What's the best way to serialize more than one model to json in Django 1.6?

Tags: python, json, serialization, django-views

I have 3 models show as below.

```
    class DocumentClass(models.Model):
        text = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    class DocumentGroup(models.Model):
        text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        documentclass = models.ForeignKey(DocumentClass)


    class DocumentType(models.Model):
        text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        documentgroup = models.ForeignKey(DocumentGroup)
```

And my goal is something like this:

```
[
    {
        'pk': 1,
        'model': 'DocumentClass',
        'fields':{
            'text':'DocumentClass1',
            'documentgroup':
            [
                {
                    'pk': 1,
                    'model': 'DocumentGroup'
                    'field':
                    {
                        'text':'DocumentGroup1'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'pk': 2,
        'model': 'DocumentClass',
        'fields':{
            'text':'DocumentClass2'
        }
    }
]
```

I usually serialize a model by

```
jsonstr = serializers.serialize("json", DocumentType.objects.all())
```

But for my goal. I have no idea.
As the title. What is the best way to do that?

Edit:
The relation of above models look like:

```
DocumentClass1
|-DocumentGroup1
| |-DocumentType1
| |-DocumentType2
| |-...
|-DocumentGroup2
| |-...
DocumentClass2
|-DocumentGroup...
| |-DocumentType...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If The Models Are Related

This will require some more customized serialization, for which you will have to use [Django Rest Framework's serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

Try subclassing `ModelSerializer`:

```
class DocumentTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DocumentType


class DocumentGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    types = DocumentTypeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentGroup


class DocumentClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = DocumentGroupSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentClass


queryset = DocumentClass.objects.all()
serializer = DocumentClassSerializer(queryset, many=True)
json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
```

### If The Models Are Not Related

According to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/serialization/#serializing-data), the 2nd argument to `serialize()` can be "any iterator that yields Django model instances".

Now you'll need to pass your 3 kinds of instances as an iterator. It seems like Python's `itertools.chain` is the preferred method, as voted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434755/245915).

So your call would look something like:

```
instances = list(chain(DocumentClass.objects.all(), DocumentGroup.objects.all(), DocumentType.objects.all())
jsonstr = serializers.serialize("json", instances)
```

Comment: Thanks nofinator, But the relation of those models look like DocumentClass{DocumentGroup{DocumentType}} not only chain T-T

Comment: @PrukAmbavamata I just updated my answer. I think you will have to use Django Rest Framework.

Answer (score 0):

As I follow by @nofinator's answer in "If The Models Are Related" section everything looks fine until `json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)`I got above errors. How can I eliminate them?

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `documenttypes` on serializer `DocumentGroupSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `DocumentGroups` instance.
Original exception text was: 'DocumentGroups' object has no attribute 'documenttypes'.
```

Here is my serialize.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *


class DocumentTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DocumentTypes
        fields = ('id', 'text')


class DocumentGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    documenttypes = DocumentTypeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentGroups
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'documenttypes')


class DocumentClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    documentgroups = DocumentGroupSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentClasses
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'documentgroups')
```

And this is my models.py

```
from django.db import models


class DocumentClasses(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class DocumentGroups(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    documentclass = models.ForeignKey(DocumentClasses)


class DocumentTypes(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    documentgroup = models.ForeignKey(DocumentGroups)
```

Update.
When I try to add `read_only=True` my serializer.py look like

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class DocumentTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DocumentTypes
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'documentgroup')


class DocumentGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    documenttypes = DocumentTypeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentGroups
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'documenttypes')


class DocumentClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    documentgroups = DocumentGroupSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentClasses
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'documentgroups')
```

Then try:

```
queryset = DocumentClasses.objects.all()
serializer = DocumentClassSerializer(queryset, many=True)
json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
```

I got only `'[{"id":1,"text":"class1"}]'` 
But this is my expected:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "text":"class1",
      "documentgroups":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "text":"group1",
            "documenttypes":[  
               {  
                  "id":1,
                  "text":"type1"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @nofinator and other django rookie like me!
Thanks @nofinator for the great answer! And for django rookies like me. If you want to use django-rest-framework to serialize queryset **DO NOT FORGET** to use the ** **related_name** **(without ** ) attribute in the model like this:

```
class DocumentClasses(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class DocumentGroups(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    documentclass = models.ForeignKey(DocumentClasses, **related_name**='documentgroups')


class DocumentTypes(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    documentgroup = models.ForeignKey(DocumentGroups, **related_name**='documenttypes')
```

@nofinator and ralated_name made my day! Million thanks!