# How can I include multiple querysets in a django view?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Is it possible to define multiple querysets within the view function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine 2 or more querysets in a Django view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view)

Comment: Yes it is. Just add them to context. Which type of view are you using. Class based or function based?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I'm using a Class based view.

Comment: @TomHiggins Did you solve you problem?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I have! Thank you for all your help.

Comment: If my post helped. You can mark it as answer. So this question will shown  as "answered" for other users.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Sorry, I've now done that. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is example

```
class MyMultiQuerysetView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['queryset1'] = MyModel1.objects.all()
        context_data['queryset2'] = MyModel2.objects.all()
        return context_data
```

And now `queryset1` and `queryset1` are acceptable in your templates.

Answer (score 2):

## For class based views

```
class MyView(ListView):
    context_object_name = "data"
    template_name = "myapp/template.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        myset = {
            "first": Model1.objects.all(),
            "second": Model2.objects.all(),
            .
            .
            .
        }
        return myset
```

In HTML you can call them like:

```
{% for a in data.first %}
{% for a in data.second %}
```

---

## For function based views

```
def MyView(request):
    myset = {
        "first": Model1.objects.all(),
        "second": Model2.objects.all(),
        .
        .
        .
    }
    return render(request, "myapp/template.html", myset)
```

In HTML:

```
{% for a in first %}
{% for a in second %}
```