# Merge two/objects querysets with Django

Tags: python, django, datatables

I have the following piece of code. I'm using it to return json so Datatables can render it. I pass in query parameters.

```
def map_query(type_, type_model, type_pk, query_data, request):
type_results_query = None

 problem_data = get_model_query_data(query_data, Problem)
 problems_filtered = Problem.objects.filter(**problem_data)

if request.POST:
    model_query_data = get_model_query_data(query_data, type_model)
    type_results_query = Chgbk.objects.filter(**model_query_data)
    print(type_results_query)
return type_results_query
```

So type_results_query returns data I want. But Problem model has a foreign key on it which links to key on table. I want to get the data from the Problem table into the Chgbk query as well, sort of the two objects merged but I cannot figure out how to do this and it is driving me crazy.

Models would be:

```
class Chgbk(VNCModel):
    chgbk_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    facility = models.ForeignKey('Facility', models.DO_NOTHING)
    create_dt = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    mod_dt = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    carrier_scac = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    carrier_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)


class Problem(VNCModel):
    problem_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    chgbk = models.ForeignKey(Chgbk, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you post the models.py also?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work... I don't understand why this is so difficult, I essentially want to create a model out of all these fields :)