# Evaluate multiple querysets in a single db call

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Lets suppose I have a list of unevaluated querysets:

```
q_list = [a.objects.all(), b.objects.all(),...]
```

I want to evaluate all of them at once in a single database call. I can iterate over the list and evaluate them individually like this:

```
evaluated_q_list = map(list, q_list)
```

But that will make multiple db queries. Is it possible to do this in a single db query using Django ORM?

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view

Comment: @Pabasara Ranathunga That question is about concatenating list, I want to minimize round trip time by evaluating all querysets in single call.

Comment: doesn't the q_list already gets evaluated? Try printing the length of each element in q_list

Comment: No, it doesn't. Here's is the small test:
`from django.db import connection
 l = [a.objects.all()]
 print(len(connection.queries)) # Will print 0`

Answer (score 1):

If what you want here is to combine two queries with the SQL `UNION` operation, [Django supports that as a QuerySet method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#union).

But it's not clear why you want to try to force this into a single query; more information about your use case would help in coming up with suggestions.

Comment: I cannot use UNION as I am using django 1.8. Regarding the use case, I want to minimize the IO operations as the database may be present in the different machine connected via network.

Comment: Many production Django deployments involve a database on a separate machine. While it's good to think about how to reduce query counts, trying to force a single query for everything is premature optimization; first, get your app running, then profile it and see where the performance hits are, and use things like caching or more efficient queries as your first resort.