# How to merge two differently ordered queryset from same model together one after another in django

Tags: python, django, merge, django-queryset

I have tried

```
work_orders = WorkOrder.objects.all()

active_wo = work_orders.filter(status=OPEN).order_by('-raised_on')

completed_wo = work_orders.filter(status=COMPLETE).order_by('-completed_on')
```

But when i merge these above querysets together as

`work_orders = completed_wo | active_wo`

all i want to get is either active_wo objects followed by completed_wo or viceversa
i am not getting proper ordered queryset as i expected.
i am getting `work_orders` in ordered by its pk

Please advice me a solution i need queryset as output as i have many filtering yet to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view

Comment: @ Sachin Kukreja. i don't want to sort the resulted list in a particular way. see all i wanted my active_list first then completed_list .or just opposite

Comment: `list(chain(...))` method didn't work for you then?

Comment: @Sachin Kukreja
it works but i don't want list as result. i want queryset as result dude

Comment: i'm facing the same issue