# Django how to join two query sets so that they are sequentially serialized

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a model call `MyModel` defined as below

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
     fk = models.ForeignKey('AnotherModel')
     rank = models.FloatField()
```

I wish to create a query set for serialization so that instances with `instance.fk.other_fk_id` in some set comes before the ones that don't and then sorted by decreasing rank.

So I wish to join

```
a = MyModel.objects.filter(fk__other_fk_id__in=some_set).order_by('-rank')
```

and

```
b = MyModel.objects.exclude(fk__other_fk_id__in=some_set).order_by('-rank')
```

sequentially so that a comes before b when it's handed to the serializers. Any idea on how to achieve this functionality efficiently? (let's say there is 50 instances in `a` and 200000 instances in `b` so I cannot directly concat those two as lists).

The end goal is to feed it into a custom serializer w/ pagination, say, to present in a webpage.

Comment: What is the advantage of making this one query instead of two?

Comment: a and b is same query?

Comment: What is the difference between the two queries?

Comment: sry second one should be exclude, fixed

Comment: There is another link to your answer. Hope this helps.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I figured this out. What you can do is to annotate another value, join them and sort by two fields.

```
a = a.annotate(rank2=Value(1, IntegerField()))
b = b.annotate(rank2=Value(0, IntegerField()))
qs = a.union(b).order_by('-rank2', '-rank')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("xml", chain(a, b))
```

Comment: why the 'xml'? would this work for a customized serializer?

Comment: I'm just using XML as an example. You can serialize the chained querysets in any way you want. Yes it would work for a customized serializer.

Comment: It should be mentioned: this does not actually create a query set, which the question actually asked for.  I'm not sure whether that's actually important, but it *might* be very important (for example if the db has changed in between evaluation of two queries).

Comment: I just need it to put it in a custom serializer, not exactly a queryset

Comment: that seems to union the query but does not guarantee the order?