# Querying multiple tables and returning a combined queryset in Django while hitting the database once

Tags: python, django

Lets say I have the following models setup:

```
class X(models.Model):
     ...

class Y(models.Model):
     x = models.ForeignKey(X)

class Z(models.Model):
     x = models.ForeignKey(X)
```

Now, in a method, I want to get all the `Y` objects and `Z` objects that are related to a given `X` object. I want to hit my database once, and return a combined queryset. Right now, I am doing it like this:

```
x = X.objects.get(pk=1)
queryset = []
for cls in [Y, Z]:
    queryset += list(cls.objects.filter(x=x))
```

Note: running it through a loop is important because there are quite a few models in my actual code, so looping keeps the whole thing DRY. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: @Pedro Could you please expand your comment into an answer with code examples using my model names?

Comment: my bad, you can't do ```select_related``` from a reverse foreign key. You can use ```prefetch_related```, but it will hit the database multiple times: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Answer (score 1):

If you need to merge to querysets from different models, the best/fastest way is by using [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434755). Keep in mind this converts it from a `QuerySet` to an ordinary `List`.

```
from itertools import chain
x = X.objects.get(pk=1)
y = Y.objects.filter(x=x)
z = Z.objects.filter(x=x)
result_list = list(chain(y, z))
```

As far as I know, there isn’t a way to query two different models that way, even with `select_related` or `prefetch_related`.

Comment: The conversion to list is fine. This would hit the database only once, correct?