# Merge queryset from two databases in Django Rest

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two routes in my api looking like that :

http://mywebsite/websites/website_1/annonces/

http://mywebsite/websites/website_2/annonces/

I need to make an ListAPIView merging these 2 routes but each route call its own database.

The two databases are made with the same django Model. I made two databases because it suits my architecture better.

The problem is that I have no column in my databases which indicates the website the records are from. The records are only differentiated by the names of their database.

I want to get all record in a single route but also being able to tell from which database they are from in the json response.

```
 class Annonce(models.Model):
     annonce_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
     annonce_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
     url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
     region = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

 class AnnoncesList(generics.ListAPIView):
     authentication_classes = ()
     permission_classes = ()
     serializer_class = AnnonceListSerializer
     pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination
     filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
     filterset_fields = ('advert_type', 'asset_type', 'sales_type', 'price', 'area', 'department', 'department_id', 'city', 'postal_code')

     def get_queryset(self):
         queryset = Annonce.objects.using(self.kwargs["website_name"]).all()
         return queryset
```

Comment: Please, share the code for your models and your views

Comment: @HuLuViCa Ok it's done

Answer (score 1):

Make the queryset for each database, then use [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) to add a column `website_name` for each record on queryset. Concatenate the querysets into a list (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434755/7727181)) (will hit all items on database), make sure the querysets have already been properly filtered.

```
from itertools import chain

from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from django.db.models import Value, CharField


class AnnonceMergedList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = AnnonceMergedListSerializer
    queryset = Annonce.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        # Make the querysets for each database
        q1 = self.get_queryset().using('website_1').annotate(website_name=Value('website_1', CharField()))
        q2 = self.get_queryset().using('website_2').annotate(website_name=Value('website_2', CharField()))

        # Filtering the querysets
        q1 = self.filter_queryset(q1)
        q2 = self.filter_queryset(q2)

        # Merge (hit items on database)
        data = list(chain(q1, q2))

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The serializer for this view must receive the `website_name` to display the website the records are from

```
class AnnonceMergedListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    website_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True) # Field from annotation

    class Meta:
        model = Annonce
        fields = ('website_name', ...)
```

Comment: looks good but I get that error : Response' object has no attribute 'model

Comment: Do you override `get_queryset` method? I guess this error happens when DRF try to retrieve the model through `get_queryset` return, but the method returned a `Response` object instead a queryset. In this sample I not override `get_queryset` method, only the `queryset` property

Comment: Yes I did override ```python get_queryset```. I not finding a way to merge 2 queryset with two different _db and still return a queryset and not a Response object.