# Django: searching in related models

Tags: python, django

Hello I want to create simple search form which will allow to get data from related models.

I have 3 models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    surname = models.CharField()

class Phone(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="phones")
    phone = models.CharField(0

class Email(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="emails")
    email = models.EmailField()
```

in my home view I have:

```
def home(request):
    people = Person.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        people = Person.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query)|Q(surname__icontains=query)|
                 Q(emails__contains=query)|Q(phones__icontains=query))
    //when I try emails_email__icontains=query I get error about no such fields

    return render(request,'app/home.html',{'users': people})
```

And it works fine, but I would like to search throug emails and phones too (person can have fews email and phone). 
If in my query I use another OR (|), I got error I cant combine 2 models in one query.
I also wanto to try with chain:

```
people= above query
emails = Email.objects.filter(email__icontains=query)
context = chain(people,emails)
```

Unfortunately, this solution doesnt work too.
How can I solve this?

**EDIT: TEMPLATE**

```
{% block content %}
   {%for user in users %}
      {{user.id }} {{user.name}} {{user.surname}}
      {% for email in user.email_set.all %}
         {{email}}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

in models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    surname = models.CharField()

class Phone(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='a')
    phone = models.CharField(0

class Email(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='b')
    email = models.EmailField()
```

in filter

```
from django.db.models import Q

people = Person.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query)|Q(surname__icontains=query)|Q(b__email__icontains=query))
```

in template

```
{% block content %}
{% for user in users %}
    {{user.id }} {{user.name}} {{user.surname}}
    {% for email in user.b.all %}
       {{email.email}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Well, when I added related_name to my models, they aren't displayed in my html file. Before I had: {% for email in user.email_set.all %} which was working. And after changes is not. I tried {% for email in user.emails %}, but nothing is displayed

Comment: I added my template

Comment: so atm phones and emails are displayed. But when I want to search I get FieldErros - Related Field go invalid lookup: icontains

Comment: @Frendom use double underscore **emails__email__icontains**

Comment: It works, thank you. THe only problem is if user has few emails or phones he is displayed multiple times after searching

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Q` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

models:

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="phones")
    phone = models.CharField(0

class Email(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="emails")
    email = models.EmailField()
```

views:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def home(request):
    people= Person.objects.all()
    query - request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        people = Person.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(surname__icontains=query) | Q(emails__email__icontains=query) | Q(phones__phone__icontains=query))

    return render(request,'app/home.html',{'users': people})
```

[use chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view)

Comment: I undestand that after using Q I can: Person.objcets.filter(Q(emails__icontains=query))?

Comment: you can do that like this: `Person.objcets.filter(Q(emails__email__icontains=query))`

Answer (score 1):

To what I understand of the question, you basically need a union of people having the search query either as an email or as a phone.

```
    Person.objects.filter(Q(mobile__icontains=query)|Q(email__icontains=query))
```

The above query will return the list of Person objects as a result.
This is basically a reverse lookup which will search all models having Person as a foreign key and having fields namely mobile and email.