# Django. Search in multiple models

Tags: django

Help to unite search in several models.
I have two models `Apartment` and `Houses`. These models have the same strings `State`. According to them, I customize the search in `views.py`. It looks like this:

**views.py**

```
def search(request):
    queryset_list = Houses.objects.order_by('-list_date')

     if 'state' in request.GET:
        state = request.GET['state']
        if state:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(state__iexact=state)

context = {
        'queryset_list': queryset_list,
    }

    return render(request, '/search-templates/search.html', context)
```

As a result, I see `Houses` from the selected region. I understand that the search is conducted in the model `Houses`. It works great!

```
queryset_list = Houses.objects.order_by('-list_date')
```

**Question:**
How to combine search? Show objects from two models `Apartment` and `Houses`.

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write two query:

```py
houses_list = Houses.objects.order_by('-list_date')
apartment_list = Apartment..objects.order_by('-list_date')

if state:
            houses_list = houses_list.filter(state__iexact=state)
            apartment_list = apartment_list.filter(state__iexact=state)
```

And then combine your query_sets like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/434755/6265279

```py
from itertools import chain
queryset_list = list(chain(houses_list, apartment_list))
```

Comment: **Saeed Alijani**, this is exactly what I need. Everything works, thank you so much for the answer.