# How to combine multiple querysets in django

Tags: python, django

Suppose there is an event model and for each event there is one client and one consultant. Also, one consultant can have multiple events. Each event has number of different documents. I am trying to display list of events when a consultant logs in and in that list od events it should display their respective documents.

Models.py:

```
class Client_Profile(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # Field name made lowercase.
    first_name = models.CharField(db_column='First_name', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    last_name = models.CharField(db_column='Last_name', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column='Phone_number', max_length=10)  # Field name made lowercase.
    # role_id = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


class Consultant_Profile(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # Field name made lowercase.
    first_name = models.CharField(db_column='First_name', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    last_name = models.CharField(db_column='Last_name', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column='Phone_number', max_length=10)  # Field name made lowercase.
    # role_id = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


class Event(models.Model):
    event_id = models.AutoField(db_column='event_id', primary_key=True)
    client_id = models.ForeignKey(Client_Profile, db_column='Client_ID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # Field name made lowercase.
    consultant_id = models.ForeignKey(Consultant_Profile, db_column='Consultant_ID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.event_id)


class Document(models.Model):
    document_id = models.AutoField(db_column='document_id', primary_key=True)
    document_name = models.CharField(db_column='document_name', max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    path = models.FileField(null=True, upload_to='files/')
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(Event, db_column='Client_ID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __str__(self):
        return self.document_name + ": " + str(self.path)  # this specifies how should instance of this class should be printed.
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def consultant_home(request):
    consultant_pr = Consultant_Profile.objects.get(user_id=request.user)
    event_id = Event.objects.filter(consultant_id=consultant_pr.pk)
    for id in event_id:
        doc = Document.objects.filter(event_id=id)
    context = {'id': event_id, 'doc': doc, 'consultant_pr': consultant_pr}
    return render(request, 'Consultant/consultant_documents.html', context)
```

document.html

```
                    {% for eve in id %}
                    <p>Event id: {{ eve.event_id }}</p>
                        {% for dox in doc %}
                            <p>document name: {{ dox.document_name }}</p>
                            <p>path: <a href="/media/{{dox.path}}">{{ dox.path}} </a> </p>
                        {% endfor%}
                    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: it's discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-can-i-combine-two-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view) with details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I combine two or more querysets in a Django view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-can-i-combine-two-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view)

Comment: _combine_ is quite a misnomer for what you want, you don't want to combine querysets, you just want the related instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply loop over the related `Document` objects from the `Event` object itself by using `document_set` (the default `related_name` for `Document` i.e. the model name in lowercase with `_set` appended). Also you can optimise the number of queries made by using [`prefetch_related` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

In your view:

```
@login_required
def consultant_home(request):
    consultant_pr = Consultant_Profile.objects.get(user_id=request.user)
    events = Event.objects.filter(consultant_id=consultant_pr.pk).prefetch_related('document_set')
    context = {'events': event, 'consultant_pr': consultant_pr}
    return render(request, 'Consultant/consultant_documents.html', context)
```

In your template:

```
{% for event in events %}
    <p>Event id: {{ event.event_id }}</p>
    {% for document in event.document_set.all %}
        <p>document name: {{ document.document_name }}</p>
        <!-- Use document.path.url instead of manually rendering its url -->
        <p>path: <a href="{{ document.path.url }}">{{ document.path }} </a></p>
    {% endfor%}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i tried that still giving error saying "Cannot find 'document' on Event object, 'document' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()"

Comment: @YASHJARIWALA try `.prefetch_related('document_set')` instead?

Comment: now it is just displaying the event id not the list of documents for an event

Comment: oh....its done now thanks