# How to mix multiple querysets into one and re order them by time created?

Tags: django

I am learning Django and still a beginner. For practising, i am trying to make a demo social media website. In my project, users can create groups, then they can post and comment there. In the home page, i am trying to add a section like 'recent activities' where a user can see recent activities in that website like "John created a group 'Javascript', Tim posted a comment in 'Python', Sarah posted in 'CSS'" Now i have made some queries like:

`groups = Group.objects.all().order_by('-created')[0:5]
posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')[0:5]
comments = Comment.objects.all().order_by('-created')[0:5]`

I want to mix them all in a single queryset. Then order them all by the time they were created. I know it's a silly question and i have been stuck here since morning. Can you help me and show me the process please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I combine two or more querysets in a Django view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-can-i-combine-two-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain these together and order by the `created` field with:

```
from operator import attrgetter

groups = Group.objects.order_by('-created')[:5]
posts = Post.objects.order_by('-created')[:5]
comments = Comment.objects.order_by('-created')[:5]
all_items = sorted(
    [*groups, *posts, *comments],
    key=attrgetter('created'),
    reversed=True
)
```

Now `all_items` is a *hetrogenous* list with different types of objects. This will thus make the rendering process a bit more complicated since a `comment` probably has different fields than a `Post` for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `chain` function from `itertools` module to combine the querysets and then sort them in reverse order using the `created` field as key.

```
from itertools import chain

groups = Group.objects.all()[0:5]
posts = Post.objects.all()[0:5]
comments = Comment.objects.all()[0:5]

queryset = sorted(
    chain(groups, posts, comments),
    key=lambda instance: instance.created,
    reverse=True
)
```