# Combining 2 sets of model objects in alphabetical order

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

In my code, I currently have 2 models (Company and Individual Model)

Now I need to print both sets of data on the same report but it needs to be in alphabetical order

This is how I have referenced them in **views.py** separately

```
modelCompany = CompanyClass.objects.all().order_by('CompanyName')
modelIndividual = IndividualClass.objects.all().order_by('Surname')
```

But how would I be able to join them in the same list and organize them alphabetically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I combine two or more querysets in a Django view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-can-i-combine-two-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an empty dictionary and after querying for results of `CompanyClass` and `IndividualClass`, add them to your dictionary like this:

```
context = { Company: modelCompany, Individual: modelIndividual }
```

Then return this json object by `JsonResponse` or something like that

Comment: How would that join the lists in alphabetical order - this is just passing them to the template.

Comment: so you must add all of the results to an empty list and then sort them.