# Django 3.2 how to fix AttributeError: 'itertools.chain' object has no attribute 'filter' error?

Tags: python, django, ajax

I have 3 querysets that I need to merge and use `filter` method when the user selects a checkbox. Ajax works fine but I am struggling with displaying filtered data because I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'itertools.chain' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

When I am trying to iterate over 1 model like this `favourite_list=Product.objects.all()` everything works fine but in my case, I need to filter data from 3 different models.

I tried to use `list(chain(fa, fv, fp))` but it gives me `list object has no attribute filter` error.

```
def filter_favourites(request):
    favourite_articles = request.GET.getlist('favourite_articles[]')
    favourite_video = request.GET.getlist('favourite_video[]')
    favourite_product = request.GET.getlist('favourite_product[]')

    fa = request.user.favourite_article.all().distinct() #list of favourites items from Article model
    fv = request.user.favourite_video.all().distinct() #list of favourites items from Video model
    fp = request.user.favourite_product.all().distinct() #list of favourites items from Product model
    favourite_list = chain(fa, fv, fp)

    if len(favourite_articles) > 0:
        favourite_list = favourite_list.filter(title__in=favourite_articles).distinct()
    if len(favourite_video) > 0:
        favourite_list = favourite_list.filter(title__in=favourite_video).distinct()
    if len(favourite_product) > 0:
        favourite_list = favourite_list.filter(title__in=favourite_product).distinct()

    context = {
        'combined_queryset': favourite_list,
    }
    ajax_template = render_to_string('user/user_favourites_ajax.html', context)
    
    return JsonResponse({'data': ajax_template})
```

My question is how can I fix this error? How should I merge `fa, fv, pd` so they behave like normal querysets and I can use `filter` method on them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I combine two or more querysets in a Django view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-can-i-combine-two-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**filter** method is for objects with type of **QuerySet**, so you can't use it on list and chain. 
instead you can group the favourites after filtering

```
def filter_favourites(request):
    favourite_articles = request.GET.getlist('favourite_articles[]')
    favourite_video = request.GET.getlist('favourite_video[]')
    favourite_product = request.GET.getlist('favourite_product[]')

    fa = request.user.favourite_article.all().distinct() #list of favourites items from Article model
    fv = request.user.favourite_video.all().distinct() #list of favourites items from Video model
    fp = request.user.favourite_product.all().distinct() #list of favourites items from Product model

    if len(favourite_articles) > 0:
        fa = fa.filter(title__in=favourite_articles)
    if len(favourite_video) > 0:
        fv = fv.filter(title__in=favourite_video)
    if len(favourite_product) > 0:
        fp = fp.filter(title__in=favourite_product)
    
    favourite_list = chain(fa, fv, fp)
    
    context = {
        'combined_queryset': favourite_list,
    }
    ajax_template = render_to_string('user/user_favourites_ajax.html', context)
    
    return JsonResponse({'data': ajax_template})
```

and no need to use distinct again after conditions, it has done once before

edited:

```
def filter_favourites(request):
    favourite_articles = request.GET.getlist('favourite_articles[]')
    favourite_video = request.GET.getlist('favourite_video[]')
    favourite_product = request.GET.getlist('favourite_product[]')

    favourite_titles = favourite_articles + favourite_video + favourite_product

    favourites_items_list = [
        request.user.favourite_article.all().distinct(), #list of favourites items from Article model
        request.user.favourite_video.all().distinct(),   #list of favourites items from Video model
        request.user.favourite_product.all().distinct(), #list of favourites items from Product model
    ]

    if len(favourite_titles) > 0:
        for ind, f in enumerate(favourites_items_list):
            favourites_items_list[ind] = f.filter(title__in=favourite_titles)
    
    favourite_list = chain(*favourites_items_list)
    
    context = {
        'combined_queryset': favourite_list,
    }
    ajax_template = render_to_string('user/user_favourites_ajax.html', context)
    
    return JsonResponse({'data': ajax_template})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Your solution works however it filters items only within a particular model, not it chained queryset.

Comment: @Adrian check the edited one, does it fix what you said?

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems that `QuerySet.union()` is [what you're looking for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.union).

```
favourite_list = fa.union(fv, fp)
```

As for your initial question, neither `list` nor `intertools.chain` (which is the type returned by `itertools.chain()`) types have a `filter()` method, hence the errors.

```py
>>> chain(["a"], ["b"])
<itertools.chain object at 0x7fd3f0a86580>
```

Comment: I get the following error `django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Calling QuerySet.filter() after union() is not supported.`