# How to combine AND and OR conditions in django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-views, orm

I have one sql query:

```sql
select * from sample_table where (istatus = 1 AND ((iCategory = 2 and iType=1) or (iType in (2,3,5)));
```

How can I write the same in Django ORM using filter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine multiple QuerySets in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-multiple-querysets-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this using [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for complex queries:

```
from django.db.models import Q

SampleModel.objects.filter(
    Q(istatus=1),
    Q(i_category=2, i_type=1) | Q(i_type__in=[2,3,5])
)
```