# Combining two Queryset for sorting , Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I have two Queryset result. I need to combine before it gets sorted. How to solve this problem in Django? And it should convert it back to Queryset for sending it to template.

Tried to convert it to a list but its not converts back  to Queryset.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-multiple-querysets-in-django answer your question?

Comment: Can you please provide the two querysets?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the union operator

```
queryset3 = queryset1 | queryset2
```